# Android content provider URI doesn't work after reboot

Tags: android, permissions, uri

In short, when I pick an logo image from an intent and store the URI I can display/load the image. This works even when I exit the app and start it again.
But when I reboot the tablet I have permission problems.

Long version:

The user can pick an image

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19){
            intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("image/*");
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
            intent.setType("image/*");
        }
```

then, I'm storing the content provider URI to my app's database, which looks like this:

```
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A53
```

the image is loaded to an imageView

```
myLogo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(f.getLogo_uri()));
```

When I close the app and start it again the logo is loaded - everything works fine.
But when I reboot the tablet, I get this message

```
ImageView﹕ Unable to open content: content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A53
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider 
com.android.providers.media.MediaDocumentsProvider from ProcessRecord
{x y:clazz.stuff} (pid=blah, uid=blah) requires android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS 
or android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS
```

but my AndroidManifest.xml is granting that permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

any help is appreciated, thanks!

p.s. I'm on android kitkat 4.4.4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, there is no requirement for a `Uri` to a `ContentProvider` to be durable. They are for immediate consumption and may not necessarily work at arbitrary times in the future.

Second, there is no requirement for you to have the rights to use a valid `Uri` in the future, particularly with the Storage Access Framework on Android 4.4 (your `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` path). The provider might be offering you more durable permissions, but you have to call `takePersistableUriPermission()` for that. See the "Persist Permissions" section of [the Storage Access Framework documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html) for more.

Your specific error feels like the second problem outlined above.

> but my AndroidManifest.xml is granting that permission

You cannot hold the `MANAGE_DOCUMENTS` permission unless you are signed by the firmware's signing key, as that is a `signature` permission.

Comment: Is it good practice to store the Uri then? If not what would be the correct durable way? Thanks I'll test takePersistableUriPermission().

Comment: @MichaelD.: "Is it good practice to store the Uri then?" -- you are welcome to store a `Uri`, so long as you do not mind that the data may be gone or your access may be gone. "If not what would be the correct durable way?" -- I cannot what is "correct" as I have no idea what you are doing. If you cannot handle your data being gone or otherwise unavailable, copy the data into your own app.

Comment: Even if I check that I have permission, can I assume that the Uri will continue to point to the same data after a reboot or media scan? Or do the image/video etc ids get reallocated, meaning I might end up loading the wrong image after retrieving a stored Uri?

Comment: @samgak: That would be a question for the authors of the `ContentProvider`. If you are referring to the `MediaStore`, I *think* that those `Uri` values are durable, but I do not know for certain.